# eclipse / Zend Studio: How to add PHP servers and debug configurations from outside?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, automation, zend-studio

Is it possible to create new PHP servers

[image]

and debug configurations sets

[image]

[image]

outside of eclipse? What files do I need to create/change to do this?

I want to write a script to automate this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an [answer](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/455361/1012283/#msg_1012283) in the Eclipse Community Forum.

> PHP Servers are persisted in
>   {workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.php.server.core.prefs
>
> Debug(Launch) configurations are stored in
>   {workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
>
> (editing those files directly is contrary to manners of course)